# Unknown Java Recursion error

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write recursive code to find all the exit paths of a square grid and I get some error 
at Project4.escape(Project4.java:41)
I have no idea what the error is though, because the following line:

at Project4.escape(Project4.java:41)

is repeated so often that the error message isn't visible. Please help me find the problem, and fix it. What follows is my escape method.

```
private static void escape(int row, int col, int[][] swamp,String escapePath)
    {
        if (row == swamp.length || row==0 || col == 0 || col == swamp.length)
        {
            //winner
            System.out.println(escapePath);

        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j=-1;j<2;j++)
                {
                    if (row+i>=0 && j+col>=0 && row+i<swamp.length && col+j<swamp.length &&
                    swamp[row + i][col + j] == 1)
                    {
                        escapePath+="["+row+","+col+"]";
                        swamp[row][col]=2;
                        escape(row,col,swamp,escapePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        swamp[row][col]=1;
    }
```

//EDIT: what follows now is the main method, which shows what I call escape with initially.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int[] dropInPt = new int[2]; // row and col will be on the 2nd line of input file;
        int[][] swamp = loadSwamp( args[0], dropInPt ); //returns an 8 by 8 grid of 0s and 1s and fills dropInPt with 1s
        int row=dropInPt[0], col = dropInPt[1];
        printSwamp(          "\n   SWAMP: dropped in at: ["+row+","+col+"]\n",swamp );
        System.out.println("\n   ESCAPE PATHS:\n");


        String escapePath = "["+dropInPt[0]+","+dropInPt[1]+"]";
        escape(row,col,swamp,escapePath);


    }
```

Comment: Which line is 41?  And what is the entire error message?  You're not getting just "some" error message.

Comment: escape(row,col,swamp,escapePath);

Comment: Okay, I see that recursion is preventing you from seeing the error message.  Have you tried setting a break point?  I'd set a breakpoint, and add an output line.

Comment: What arguments do you call this method with initially?

Comment: Edited in the main method to show what escape is initially called with.

Comment: And I don't use Eclipse or anything, just cmd, so I don't know a way to set a break point so that I can see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stackoverflow error. Since you're calling `escape(row,col,swamp,escapePath);` repeatedly without changing the state of the first cell in the for loops.

My guess for a fix is to change `row` and `col` in

```
swamp[row][col]=2;
escape(row,col,swamp,escapePath);
```

to `row+i` and `col+j`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. It runs now, and there are other errors (out of bounds) but this issue is fixed.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted (the big checkmark to your left) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like row and col are never being reassigned - each time the function recurs, it's running on the same input. Recursion will never end, resulting in a stack overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

Probable stackoverflowerror caused by execution of same recursion again and again. At the inner nested for loops you do not need to calculate when  `i==0 and j==0` this calculates same point again and again.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the problem is coming up because you have "col" in quotes. Try replacing this:

```
escapePath+="["+row+","+"col"+"]";
```

with this:

```
escapePath+="["+row+","+col+"]";
```